# Android studio through Multi Dex error in my project

Tags: android

I tried to run my app in ANdroid Studio  but I have this error :

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient$1;
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I don't know  where is the problem. 
I am not able to modify and run anything as it don't run anymore.

Thank's in advance for you're help.

For example my class mainactivity have one error in :

```
addOnPageChangeListener
```

My gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.picse.kids_phone"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

my libs :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a17oo.png)

Comment: Provide complete log. But before anything try to clean your project and then build

Comment: I have clean and this no change the problem

Answer (score 0):

On that screenshot you also have jar for gson. Here's the gradle for gson:

```
//gson 2.2.2
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
```

Dont forget add the maven

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```